# Join samba4 member server

Tags: centos6, samba4

I am installing Samab4-ad in a test environment, to prepare migration from Samba3.

All is done is OpenVZ VEs running CentOS 6.

I have successfully installed DC1 and DC2 using sernet-samba rpms following these guides and making some adjustments to smb.conf and krb5.conf:

http://folgaizer.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/samba4-on-centos-6-4/
http://folgaizer.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/add-additional-domain-controller-with-samba4/

DC1 runs a bind9 nameserver. I have connected a windows box to the network to test functionality and all looks good. I can setup remote authentication as expected.

Now I am trying to configure 2 member servers, a share-fileserver and a print server.

I have installed them modifying slightly the procedure for the second DC:

```
samba-tool domain join example.local MEMBER -Uadministrator --realm=example.local
```

I get a "succesfully joined" message, but the member server does not replicate with the DCs, and the shares are not accessible:

```
samba-tool user list
```

only shows the default users. 
DC1 and DC2 on the other hand replicate as expected between each other.

```
samba-tool drs showrepl
```

Fails with the following errors:

```
Failed to connect to ldap URL 'ldap://fs.example.local' - LDAP client internal error: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Failed to connect to 'ldap://fs.example.local' with backend 'ldap': (null)
ERROR(ldb): LDAP connection to fs.example.local failed - None
```

Thanks